# DataAnnotations Not working on submit of form of a partial view called with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#divInfoRecherche :input").serialize(),
    url: '@Url.Action(Action, Controler)',
    success: function(resultat) {
        $("#tableauResultatRecherche").css("display", "");
        $("#tableauResultatRecherche").html(resultat);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#PartialViewModel'));
    }
});
```

The line `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#PartialViewModel'));` makes it possible for the client side validation to pop, everything works fine. 
Problem is when I click on Submit of the page, the message errors go back to the error of native JavaScript "This field is required" instead of my custom message linked in the model.

Option I think of is add the content of the partial view in the main view and populate it manually so that all the validations are added on Pageload.

But I still ask to see if another option is possible.

Answer (score 0):

https://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/
Here is the script to add and call on the div containing the partial view.